# Removing keys and values from map

Tags: clojure

I have a map that looks like this:

```
{\a [\h] 
 \h [\w \w]
 \i [\w \h \t]
 \p [\t \u \h \a]
 \s [\t \a \t \t \i \w \h]
 \t [\a]
 \u [\t \t \s]
 \w []}
```

I want to remove e.g. \w from both keys and values. i.e. leaving this

```
{\a [\h] 
 \h []
 \i [\h \t]
 \p [\t \u \h \a]
 \s [\t \a \t \t \i \h]
 \t [\a]
 \u [\t \t \s]}
```

Notice, the \w key has gone and \w has gone from all the values!

Right now I have this, which works, but I'm sure there must be a better, more Clojurey way!

```
(defn remove-last [last cmap]
  (reduce-kv (fn [acc k v]
               (if (empty? v)
                 acc
                 (into acc {k (vec (filter #(not= % last) v))}))) {} cmap))
```

The key to remove will always be an empty vector.

How can I do this better?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I find your solution quite idiomatic. The requirement is unusual enough, that I immediately think `reduce`. Your call to `empty?` is not according to your spec, though. You'd have to test for the key `k` being `=` to `last`.

Also, I wouldn't use the name `last` here. It clashes with a name that is already present.

A very similar alternative would be

```
(defn remove-all-of [it m] 
  (reduce
   (fn [acc [k v]] 
     (if (not= it k)
       (assoc acc
              k
              (into (empty v)
                    (filter #(not= it %) v)))
       acc))
   {}
   m))
```

This also allows you to have some other seqable thing than vectors as values by using `(empty v)`.

Comment: Oh, I'll update the question. I forgot to add that the key to be removed will always have an empty vector!

Comment: Will it be the only key with an empty vec? If so, you don't have to pass that key (`\w` in your example)

Comment: Yes, if the value to remove is \x then the key \x will always be empty, and will be the only empty vector.

Comment: In that case, you could iterate over the map once to find the thing to remove and then a second time to remove it. Depends on how large your map will get and how you prefer your function from the caller's perspective.

Comment: Minor note: `(filter #(not= it %) v)` can be written as `(remove #{it} v)` for clarity

Comment: Some voice was nagging me in the back of my head but I just didn't listen. ;-)

Answer (score 8):

what i would propose, is to first dissoc the \w key from the map (considering this is ~constant time operation), and then use the transducer to reshape the sequence in one pass without losing the declarative style, and to eliminate verbosity of reduce, while keeping the performance. could look like this:

```
(into {}
      (map (fn [[k v]] [k (filterv #(not= \w %) v)]))
      (dissoc data \w))
```

as for me, i consider this to be more readable, than reduce/assoc or reduce/update

Answer (score 4):

I like specter so much:

```
(s/setval (s/walker (fn-> (= \w))) s/NONE {\a [\h]
                                              \h [\w \w]
                                              \i [\w \h \t]
                                              \p [\t \u \h \a]
                                              \s [\t \a \t \t \i \w \h]
                                              \t [\a]
                                              \u [\t \t \s]
                                              \w []})
```

Comment: What is the (fn-> syntax?

Comment: @akond , Specter is awesome, still this case is too plain and easily performed with idiomatic clojure, so the specific dsl is not only obsolete, but also harmful (this was opinionated :) ). Still the profit of specter for more complex data querying / transformation is undisputed.